# Zend soap autodiscovery and nillable="true" in generated WSDL

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

i'm using [Zend soap autodiscovery](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.autodiscovery.html) to generate a WSDL file for my web server. The problem is that every element of every complexType defaults to `nillable="true"`. How do i declare elements as required? I read PHPDoc but found nothing.

**EDIT:** The code:

```
class MyService {
    /**
     * Identify remote user.
     *
     * @param LoginReq
     * @return LoginResp
     */
    public function login($request) {
    // Code ....
    }
}

class LoginReq {
    /** @var string */
    public $username;
    /** @var string */
    public $password;
}
class LoginResp {
    /** @var string */
    public $errorCode;
}
```

Generated WSDL:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="LoginReq">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="username" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
      <xsd:element name="password" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="LoginResp">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="errorCode" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

**EDIT2:** I just found that to declare an element as required/optional you need to use `minOccurs/maxOcurrs`. Both of them default to 1, so every element is required by default. In order to declare an optional element, you declare it with `minOccurs="1"`. Nillable is just for allowing elements to be empty. Again, how do i declare an element as optional (so Zend adds minOccurs="0" to that element)?

Answer (score 11):

if you have a default value set in your function definition, it will be nillable.

```
public function myMethod($argument = 'hello') {
    // $argument is nillable
}
```

If that isn't it, can you post your code with doc blocks?

**EDIT:** Your code sample clarifies a lot.

If you look at Zend/Soap/Wsdl/Strategy/DefaultComplesType.php around line 76, you'll see this:

```
            // If the default value is null, then this property is nillable.
            if ($defaultProperties[$propertyName] === null) {
                $element->setAttribute('nillable', 'true');
            }
```

That is the code that is determining if your "complex type" attribute is nillable. I would try updating your code to include a default value for the strings. Something like:

```
class LoginReq {
    /** @var string */
    public $username = '';
    /** @var string */
    public $password = '';
}
```

If you do that, the `=== null` should evaluate to false. Be sure your code handles the data validation properly, though.

If that doesn't work, let me know!

Comment: Thanks for digging Zend source code!  +1 for your effort. I don't understand why default behavior is that everything is nillable but attributes with default values. Shouldn't it be the opposite? BTW I just discovered this wasn't what i was looking for. I need to know how to force `minOccurs=0` on some elements.

Comment: The only mention of minOccurs in Zend is in Zend/Soap/Wsdl/Strategy/ArrayOfTypeSequence ~line 145 and it is hard coded to 0. I have a feeling that to do what you are trying to do you are going to have to create your own library class that extends the Zend classes and adds minOccurs to the objects you need. I have done that sort of thing quite a bit, just try to keep the changes to a minimum so when you update Zend you are less likely to have a conflict.

Comment: As a side note, i discovered today that setting a public property to NULL also makes it NULLABLE. If you set anything else by default to it such as 0 or '' it becomes non-nullable in the WSDL

Answer (score 0):

There is a [functional patch](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Soap-Autodiscover-how-to-generate-minOccurs-and-maxOccurs-in-WSDL-td675932.html#a675934) available on the Zend forum. It consists in hacking DefaultComplexType.php to add the management of the minOccurs and maxOccurs attributes. This works perfectly and improves interoperability with some webservices.