# How to define minOccurs and maxOccurs in function phpDoc for Zend_Soap_Server?

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, wsdl, autodiscovery

I'm using Zend_Soap_Server to create a webservice using the autodiscovery mode in PHP, and I was wondering how to generate the restrictions(minOccurs, maxOccurs) on a specific variable/function parameter using phpDoc or any other way.

Like the following, when I'm using this phpDoc over a function say `myFunction`,

```
 /**
 *
 * @param   string $param1  Parameter One
 * @param   string $param2  Parameter Two
 * @return  array  $return
 */
```

it gives me the following message in WSDL:

```
<message name="myFunctionIn">
  <part name="param1" type="xsd:string"/>
  <part name="param2" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="myFunctionOut">
  <part name="return" type="soap-enc:Array"/>
</message>
```

So if I want to restrict the function params(`param1` & `param2`) using `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` how can I do it so that the WSDL message would be like this:

```
 <message name="myFunctionIn">
  <part name="param1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string"/>
  <part name="param2" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string"/>
 </message>
```

I've searched over the internet but couldn't find any useful information.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case some people are still interested... there is a reasonably simple patch posted on a zend framework mailing list [here](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Soap-Autodiscover-how-to-generate-minOccurs-and-maxOccurs-in-WSDL-td675932.html).
It allows to define minOccurs and maxOccurs in the following style:

```
/** 
* @var string ___FOR_ZEND_minOccurs=0 ___FOR_ZEND_maxOccurs=1 
*/ 
public $Username;
```

which is translated in the WSDL to:

```
<xsd:element name="Username" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
```

The necessary code changes need to be inserted after line 58 which looks like:

```
($element->setAttribute('type', $this->getContext()->getType(trim($matches[1][0])));)
```

code to be inserted:

```
$tempo = $property->getDocComment(); 
if (preg_match('/___FOR_ZEND_minOccurs\s*=\s*(\d+|unbounded)/',$tempo,$matches)) { 
    $element->setAttribute('minOccurs', $matches[1]); 
} 
if (preg_match('/___FOR_ZEND_maxOccurs\s*=\s*(\d+|unbounded)/',$tempo,$matches)) { 
  $element->setAttribute('maxOccurs', $matches[1]); 
}
```

Obviously, you could adapt those regular expressions if you prefer a different pattern for your definitions.

Answer (score 1):

In case this is still relevant for someone: A cleaner approach might be to implement a custom strategy class for building complex type definitions - something which is actually officially supported by Zend_Soap.

Do do this, create a class that inherits from Zend_Soap_Wsdl_Strategy_ArrayOfTypeSequence (referring to ZF 1.x, but looks similar in newer framework versions, just namespaced).

In your new class, overload the _addElementFromWsdlAndChildTypes method by copying the entire method body from the parent class.

Now you can start manipulating the code and adding a docblock parser by creating a reflection object for the given $childTypeName:

```
// add the following after 
// $element = $dom->createElement('xsd:element');
$strippedTypeName = substr($childTypeName, 4); // strip xml namespace
$reflect = new \Zend_Reflection_Class($strippedTypeName);
if ($reflect->getDocblock()->hasTag('myTagName')) {
   $tagValues = $reflect->getDocblock()->getTags('myTagName');
   // do whatever you want with your attribute values and then
   // add them to the XML element:
   $element->setAttribute($attributeName, $attributeValue);
}
```

When you're done, you can set your new class as the type strategy when creating your AutoDiscover instance:

```
new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover(
    'MyNewStrategyClass', $namespace
);
```

And you're done. Now, whenever you have a class defining a complex type that should have custom minOccurs, maxOccurs or any other settings, you can annotate the class using @myTagName tags and any syntax you like to define you attribute values, e.g.

```
/**
 * MyCustomType DocBlock description
 * @myTagName minOccurs=0
 * @myTagName maxOccurs=10
 */
class MyCustomType { ... }
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to this during a recent project. As far as I know, this is not possible in the current version of ZF (see the "[bug](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9180?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel)").

I think AutoDiscovery is only meant for the most basic WSDL generation. Or at least the current version is. Perhaps future releases will be more comprehensive.

It is great as a starting point, which you can use a template to manually build more complex constraints. Alternatively you can build your own class to handle your specific requirements (as suggested in the comments of the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041577/zend-soap-autodiscovery-and-nillable-true-in-generated-wsdl))

Comment: As far as I can tell, most of the posts I'm seeing show either lack of interest in refining the server code or claims it will be difficult to impossible to do it without breaking the code. The common consensus of most of the postings is that the autodiscovery is only meant to provide a beginning framework for the wsdl that you can then modify and return from a static file.
I'm assuming this means that the error handling for extended attributes is the programmer's responsibility and not the zend engine's.

Answer (score 0):

There is a proposal that I found including a modified code for complex types, but I'm not sure if it was ever implemented and I haven't had a chance to test it yet. Check out:

http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Soap_Wsdl_Strategy_DefaultComplexType+-+Improvement+for+the+AutoDiscover+-+Jeannie+BOFFEL